# Receiving an error when trying to execute add migration command in package manager console

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need another set of eyes to look at this. The following code is being run in visual studio and when it is idle the green sidebar indicates the syntax is correct.

However when I run an add migration in the package manager console it responds with the following error.

"Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (817)

It seems to take issue with my dependency implementation but I cannot find any instance of a missing bracket or comma.

If you can find it I will gladly provide your answer with an up vote. Thank You!

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0" //New package required for added functionality
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  }
}
```

Comment: is your comment "//New package etc" actually in the file or just here for illustration?

Comment: Solved the issue by removing the comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only problem I detect on your json is the comment you have here

```
//New package required for added functionality
```

Comments are not valid on a json structure so probably error is related to that.

Comment: You are the man! I will be sure to give you the green check vote as soon as SO allows me to do so